# Page Turn Animation to multible Xibs

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, animation

I am developing a project with many view controllers showing different controls and images in seperate xibs. I need to navigate through these views(Xibs) with page turning animation.
Any help is appreciated.

the below code gives me page CURL animation but i require the page turning effect as seen in the leaves.

-(void)swipeLeftGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{

```
pp2ViewController * viewController = [[pp2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"pp2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

                    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You will have the best results by using `UIPageViewController` with the `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` transition style.

The page view controller has a nice API and deals with a lot of the messy work of creating/destroying view controllers and managing rotation, scrolling/paging transitions etc.